# Envio de Imagenes en Base64 por Mailgun

Tags: c#, imagen, email, base64

Estoy tratando de enviar imagenes base64 en mi correo por medio de Mailgun y cuando veo el correo no las muestra, pero si lo veo desde el explorador si.
Tener en cuenta que no es 1 imagen, sino que 5, no se si es porque se hace demasiado grande el correo con el base64, habra otra forma de leer la imagen?, no la puedo tener en el servidor puesto que son miles de imagenes y las voy a traer  la base dependiendo de ciertos filtros.

Comment: Muchos clientes de correo por default bloquean las imágenes, te refieres a eso o que de plano no las carga, te sugiero mostrar imágenes y/o código html aquí para que se te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Las imagenes en un mail no se envian como `base64`, se envian como un `LinkedResource`, como explico en el articulo

[MailMessage – Adjuntar Imagen en el cuerpo del Mail (3/3)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2012/08/mailmessage-adjuntar-imagen-en-el.html)

La idea es que la definicion del html del mail use `src="cid:NombreResource"`, como ser

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2> Documento con imagen adjunta</h2>
        <img src="cid:imagen1">
    </body>
</html>
```

Para despues adjuntar la imagen como link

```
string imagePath = Path.Combine("c:\carpeta", "imagen1.jpg");
LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(imagePath);
logo.ContentId = "imagen1";
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);
```

El nombre del `ContentId` debe coincidir con el que uses en el `cid` del html